# I can't get Caffe working

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, cross-entropy

After some struggling, I decided to try a most simple task, training a network to classify weither a number is non-negtive. And I failed...

I generated the data with following code. And I'm not sure if it is right. I read the data back from the file, and it looked right, though...

```
#pragma comment(lib, "hdf5")
#pragma comment(lib, "hdf5_cpp")

#include <cstdint>

#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include <H5Cpp.h>

using namespace H5;

mt19937 rng;

float randf(float i_min, float i_max)
{
    return rng() * ((i_max - i_min) / 0x100000000) + i_min;
}

#define NAME "pos_neg"

#define TRAIN_SET_SIZE 0x100000
#define TEST_SET_SIZE 0x10000

void make(const string &i_cat, uint32_t i_count)
{
    H5File file(NAME "." + i_cat + ".h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

    hsize_t dataDim[2] = { i_count, 1 };
    hsize_t labelDim = i_count;

    FloatType dataType(PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
    DataSpace dataSpace(2, dataDim);

    DataSet dataSet = file.createDataSet("data", dataType, dataSpace);

    IntType labelType(PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    DataSpace labelSpace(1, &labelDim);

    DataSet labelSet = file.createDataSet("label", labelType, labelSpace);

    vector<float> data(i_count);
    vector<int> labels(i_count);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < i_count / 2; ++i)
    {
        labels[i * 2] = 0;
        data[i * 2] = randf(0.f, 1.f);

        labels[i * 2 + 1] = 1;
        data[i * 2 + 1] = randf(-1.f, 0.f);
    }

    dataSet.write(&data[0], PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
    labelSet.write(&labels[0], PredType::NATIVE_INT);
}

int main()
{
    make("train", TRAIN_SET_SIZE);
    make("test", TEST_SET_SIZE);
}
```

And the network looks like this

```
name: "PosNegNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "pos_neg_train.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "pos_neg_test.txt"
    batch_size: 65536
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "fc1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

And and one set of parameters I tried

```
net: "pos_neg.prototxt"
test_iter: 1
test_interval: 500
base_lr: 0.001
momentum: 0.9
momentum2: 0.999
lr_policy: "fixed"
display: 100
max_iter: 10000
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "pos_neg"
type: "Adam"
solver_mode: GPU
```

And I ran caffe.exe on Windows. And I always got loss = 0, accuracy = 0.5.

I know I must have done something wrong, but I don't know from where to look, well, other than digging up source code...

---

And I found that caffe is fairly slow. I got only around 16 iterations per second for a float[64] data with 1024 item per batch on a 1080Ti. Was it normal or I did something wrong again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `num_output: 2` in your `"fc1"`: when using `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` and/or `"Accuracy"` layers caffe expects your prediction to be a *vector* of class probabilities. In your case, you have two classes, thus this vector should be of length 2 (and not 1 as it currently stands).

---

Alternatively, you can keep `num_output: 1` and switch the loss to `"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"` layer. However, you will not be able to use `"Accuracy"` layer anymore...

Comment: It's a warning for me, and I can do less stupid things in the future :|

Comment: @BlueWanderer what you call "stupid things" = learning from your mistakes. Its priceless.